# How I do rotate a map using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, maps, jquery

How rotate map using the leaflet? I was trying here, but nothing worked. I followed this tutorial, even though it was from the mapbox, I assumed it was useful:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/navigation/

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.addTo is not a function
    at e.addControl (leaflet.js:5)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:85)
```

And in my code, I just add

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.42.2/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
```

And

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
```

I trying too http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-compass, but it cant be use for rotate map. How do I rotate the map?

Comment: Asked already at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545003/rotate-map-using-leaflet, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316704/mapbox-leaflet-map-rotation

Comment: And why can not I do that? I thought I could do this because they are different websites. One is for GIS and another is for general

Answer (score 1):

So, I was facing the same problem and, after some investigation, I found this comment on the leaflet's Github issue board. Seems like the functionality doesn't exist.

[image]